# How get new django code run with old database?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I'm sorry if the name of the question is misleading but here is the deal.

I have dump of the database that was used with old version of django app (django < 1.7).

I have a new version of code which is using django 1.7. And now I need to upgrade some server with new code while saving all data.

How I thought it would work:

Restore database, run new migration (1.7 migrations) with ./manage.py migrate.

Done!

But when I'm running migrations I have "Relation already exists error".

I know that this is happening probably because database is out of sync with migration history or something... But I don't know what to do.

EDIT1 I sense that the only way is manually create migration script or something, because there is now way to sync database with new migrations now.

So suppose a have a table in database named TABLE and two columns C1 and C2.

Now when I was migrating from 1.6 to 1.7 I've added column C3. So the initial migration looks something like this "create table TABLE with COLUMNS C1, C2, C3".

And when I will try to migrate with old database it wouldn't be ably to do this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete new columns.
2. Create initial migrations.
3. Fake initial migrations for all apps:

   ```
   python manage.py migrate --fake yourappnamehere 0001
   ```
4. Add columns, create new migrations.
5. Execute new migrations.

Comment: Um... I don't know what columns are new. So this would require manual check. Not really an option.

2. I already have migrations. Why do I need to create another one? Wouldn't it break another migrations?

Comment: 1. You can create django models from your existing database: `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py` and check what columns are new. If you db is really huge you can write simple parser which will compare your models and generated from your base.

2. As I understand your current migrations do not match database, so they have to be deleted.

Comment: No, they don't have to be deleted. The database should be changed to the state where it would be consistent with new migrations, not otherwise =)

Comment: And yes, I get it. I probably should delete the question, because I thought about this done automatially using the migration and django instruments. Of course I can do this manually, delete here and there and sync database and migrations, but that is not productive, so it's not interesting to me. While I still think that migrations in django should be able to do that.

Comment: I mean, They can sync empty database with migrations, right? So to sync not empty database with migrations is just one step further. First - from migrations find what current schema should look like, then inspect actual schema, and then make actual schema current schema adding new tables, columns or deleting them. Seems pretty easy.

Comment: Yes  your idea is right, but, unfortunately, I do not know way to do this absolutely automatically